# Append data to a nested list (sublist) in arangodb

Tags: list, nested, arangodb

I apologise if this is a dumb question but it is driving me nuts. I am fairly new to arango but usually I can muddle through and work it out, but not this time.

I want to insert another set of items into the list called 'type' in the data below. I can modify the contents of the sublist using an update but can't seem to work out how to append to the list.

FOR doc IN MAG_TEST
     filter doc._key == "3704086"
     INSERT {"Name":"Mary","datestart":"16 March 2017"} INTO doc.type

**So this** 
[
  {
    "_key": "3704086",
    "_id": "MAG_TEST/3704086",
    "_rev": "3704109",
    "name": "Flip",
    "type": [
      {
        "name": "flop",
        "sdate": "13 April 2016"
      },
      {
        "name": "flap",
        "sdate": "14 April 2017"
      }
    ]
  }
]

**becomes this**
[
  {
    "_key": "3704086",
    "_id": "MAG_TEST/3704086",
    "_rev": "3704109",
    "name": "Flip",
    "type": [
      {
        "name": "flop",
        "sdate": "13 April 2016"
      },
      {
        "name": "flap",
        "sdate": "14 April 2017"
      },
      {
        "name": "fling",
        "sdate": "18 April 2018"
      }
    ]
  }
]

Comment: Have a look at the [Array functions](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Functions/Array.html) from the AQL documentation, you'll want to `UPDATE` the document, and you can `MERGE` the new documents with the existing array. Also, you might want to look at storing your dates in [another format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format) so they can be extracted and store timezone specific information. See if you can get it going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use `UPDATE` with `APPEND` to update an attribute which contains an array of objects:

```
FOR doc IN MAG_TEST
FILTER doc._key == "3704086"
UPDATE doc WITH { type: APPEND(doc.type, {"Name":"Mary","datestart":"16 March 2017"})} IN MAG_TEST
```

In this example you:

- `FILTER` to find the document you want to update
- `UPDATE` the found document
- Use `WITH` to show which attributes you want to update
- Identify the `type` attribute as being updated
- Use `APPEND` to add a new object to the existing value of `doc.type`
- Specify the collection the updated document will be stored in, `MAG_TEST`

Hope that helps.

[Documentation on the UPDATE command](https://docs.arangodb.com/devel/AQL/Operations/Update.html)

[Documentation on Array functions](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Functions/Array.html)

Note: Don't use `MERGE` as I mentioned above, `MERGE` is used to merge the attributes of two documents into a single document. For joining arrays, `APPEND` is an option you can use. Going through the other Array Functions can help solve use cases you're sure to have when manipulating and fetching data from arrays.

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so, remember to mark the answer as accepted, or let me know if you are still having issues.